# Recieving json with html tags fails in PHP

Tags: java, php, html, json

I have a website that sends and receives string in JSON format from my Java REST server with jersey. Everything works fine until I'm trying to receive a json object with html tags.

A println on my java server tells me that this data has ben sent:

```
data sent: {"text": "Wij zijn Pixel Apps, ook wel bekend als Groep 6.<br />
Samen met onze 6 groepsleden verzorgen wij het reilen en zijlen op Ford Lommel Proving  Grounds.<br />
<br />
<b>Korte inleiding</b><br />
<p>Onze taak bestaat er uit een functionele applicatie te maken binnen Windows 8. De app bestaat er uit de chauffeurs te begeleiden op hun testritten.<br />De chauffeurs worden onder andere geholpen bij het bekijken van hun routineplan, het bijhouden van notities en het overzetten van de resultaten naar het hoofdgebouw.</p>
<b>Bijkomende hoort natuurlijk het onderhouden van deze website.</b>
<p>Zoals u kan zien vind u hierboven het navigatiemenu.<br />
Voor meer informatie over ons project kan u terecht bij <i>Over ons</i><br />
Wenst u contact op te nemen? U kan zich wenden naar het tabblad <i>Contact</i><br />
Indien u meer over de individuele groepsleden wil weten kan u terecht bij <i>Leden</i><br />
Als u meer informatie wenst over ons project, gelieve contact op te nemen met ons en wij verzorgen uw verzoek.</p>
<b>Happy browsing!</b>"}
```

It's basically a simple json with one variable "text" and as content some HTML formatted content. I've googled my issue and it seems that this should work fine.

Here's my java GET method that fails to send json with html tags in it's content:

```
@GET
@Path("gettext")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getJson(@QueryParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("taalcode") String taalcode) {
    Connectie c  = new Connectie();
    try
    {
        c.openConnectie();
        String content = c.getCms(id, taalcode);
        if (content == null || content.equals("")) {
            content = "{ \"text\" : \"Geen tekst gevonden.\" }";
        }
        System.out.println("data send: "+content);
        return content;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("data send: { \"text\" : \"Server error, sorry.\" }");
        return "{ \"text\" : \"Server error, sorry.\" }";
    }
}
```

My put method successfully receives a json with html tags in it's content.
Here's how I receive my json objects in PHP (which again works if no html tags are present):

```
public function getCMS($id) {
    $taalcode = '';
    if($this->session->userdata('language') == 'nederlands') {
        $taalcode = 'NL';
    } else {
        $taalcode = 'EN';
    }
    $curl_instance = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_instance, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_instance, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.0.251:8084/Groep1/webresources/cmspost/gettext?id='.$id.'&taalcode='.$taalcode);

    try {
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl_instance), true);
        if ($data == null) {
            $data['text'] = "Altough I set a string in my java get method if it's null, this message is always printed";
        }
        return $data;
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {
        $data['text'] = $ex;
        return $data;
    }
}
```

In PHP I test `if ($data == null)` which is always true, even though I set a string manually in my GET method if appears to be null before sending the string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with HTML. The problem is that JSON does not allow multi-line strings. If you remove the line breaks, your JSON works fine.

NB that you really should use a JSON library for building JSON, rather than doing it yourself, because it will deal with this kind of issue.

Comment: That's it! Curious I didn't find any info on that :/